What's the easiest way to solve complex valued coupled differential equations in Python using SciPy?
I'm struggling to find a solution for these coupled differential equations:

dz1/dt = z1(t) H11(t) + z2(t) H12(t)

dz2/dt = z2(t) H22(t) + z1(t) H21(t)


Here, z1(t) and z2(t) are unknown functions that I would like to solve for t, and H11, H12, H21, and H22 are time-dependent coefficients of a (2,2) matrix. These matrices came from a different computation and saved as npy file.
I loaded these coefficients in a NumPy array (let's call it m) of shape (100, 2, 2). So, to access H11 at time t=15, you'd use m[14, 0, 0] and so on. Anyway, the code works fine when H12, H22 etc. are constants (either real or complex) or H12, H21 etc. have functional forms like e^(-it). But I am having trouble using them from the array. First off - I naively thought that if t is an array of 100 values, then the ODEs will be computed only on those points. Hence, H11(t) etc functions would return the corresponding coefficients at that particular time. However, it seems like even though t is discreet and has values, say, 0 1 2 etc. Somehow the ODE solver still asks the functions H22(t), H21(t) etc. to return values at points it does not have, say, t = 7.2156.
Any tips or tricks from the community would be greatly appreciated! I found complex_ode method in scipy but it don't think it is for coupled equations. I tried to use odeintw in the following code.
My code:
from odeintw import odeintw

dt = 0.1
freq = 100
num_time_steps = 100

# Define the coupled differential equations
def Haa(t): 
    return m[int(t)//freq, 0, 0]

def Hbb(t): 
    return m[int(t)//freq, 1, 1]

def Hab(t): 
    return m[int(t)//freq, 0, 1]

def Hba(t): 
    return m[int(t)//freq, 1, 0]

def equations(z, t, Haa, Hbb, Hab, Hba):
    z1, z2 = z
    dz1dt = (z1 * Haa(t) + z2 * Hab(t))
    dz2dt = (z1 * Hba(t) + z2 * Hbb(t))
    return [dz1dt, dz2dt]

# Time points

t = [step * freq * dt for step in range(num_time_steps)]

# Initial conditions
z0 = [0, 1]  # Initial values of z1 and z2

# Solve ODE
solution = odeintw(equations, z0, t, args=(Haa, Hbb, Hab, Hba))

# Extract solutions
z1, z2 = solution[:, 0], solution[:, 1]

I tried odeint and presented my code.

What do you mean by "I'm having trouble loading from an array"? You might want to interpolate the array values rather than use discrete values.

The ODE solvers in SciPy are continuous time solvers.  As you have discovered, they assume that the function can be evaluated at arbitrary times in the interval over which the system is to be solved.  Internally, the solvers are not limited to just the requested time values given in the t argument.  You have to define your system of equations so that it is defined for arbitrary values of time.  If it makes sense in your mathematical model, you could use interpolation to get the coefficents in the time between the discrete
values where you have known values, as @jared suggested.

"These matrices came from a different computation and saved as npy file." Can you move that computation into your Python code, so that the coefficients are computed at arbitrary time values as needed by the ODE solver?
